# Unable to connect GitLab with Mailgun

Tags: gitlab, mailgun

I am unable to send emails in GitLab, I am using the service Mailgun, below my settings:

```
sudo vim /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

Settings:

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = "username@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = "username@domain.com"

gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.mailgun.org"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "plain"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "username@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "secret"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "domain.com"
```

Reconfigure and restart:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Logs: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e405c81ad2d8001eee5c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All new accounts of DigitalOcean has a lock for sending emails. To remove the blockade is necessary open a ticket and request the unlock.

> To curb a recent increase in abuse and SPAM, we have an initial SMTP block on new accounts created in certain contexts.

By DigitalOcean.